# Outlook 365 Showing All Email History in One Giant List

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I just installed Outlook and linked my gmail account. Its showing my entire email history in one giant pile, going back for years. Is there a way to set up pagintion or limit the results viewed? I tried using filters, like "emails this week", but it doesnt show ALL the emails received that week for some reason, and I'd really not like to have to turn on a filter every time i log in, it messes with my search bar. I can't find anything about how to do this with Outlook 365

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to sort by date?  By default Outlook should group emails by (Today, Yesterday, Sunday, Last Week, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Ramhound, the default view setting usually sorts by date. Also, as I know, if we filter the messages via view>view settings>filter, we actually don't need to re-configure it if we restart Outlook.

If you wouldn't like to create a filter, you could try to create a search folder and set the search criteria with your need-such as receive in last week or recent 7 day(right click search folder> New search folder> create a custom Search folder>choose>set your criteria).

Also, if you configure your account with IMAP, we could also set download recent messages in last 1 month via File>Account settings>Account settings>chosse your account>Keep mail offline for

Comment: Did your issue have any update?